# Getting selected text of pdf file loaded in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, copy-paste

We can get selected text from a web view by using

```
- (NSString *)selectedText {
    return [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
}
```

But this won't work if I'm loading a PDF file.  So what I thought is that to copy the selected text and then pasting it from the `UIPasteboard` programmatically. It works fine when I click the copy button manually, but I don't want it to be like that. I want the copy cade to execute programatically. How can I make a call to it?  Or simply, How can I get the reference of the selected text from a PDF file loaded in a web view.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to this, correct me if I am wrong but I think to optimise memory footprint `UIWebView` actually draws the PDF pages as images so you don't have access to individual items (textfields, images etc). You could do this -

PDF's are nested dictionaries composed of more dictionaries & arrays. You'll have to dig into [CGPDFDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html)

Since `UIWebView` does not expose much in terms of customisation, [Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) is a good suggested alternative & starting point for rendering PDF's. Since its open-source you can change the rendering logic to select text.

Another alternative is [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com). I have used it in one of my projects & its pretty awesome. It includes full-text search, automatic thumbnail creation, single or dual page mode, view outline, page links and more

I am thinking one or a mix of the above approaches should help you get what you want & then release it as open-source for others to benefit ;)

Comment: But then how i'm getting the text when I copy the selected one manually and use the UIPasteboard to display it?

Comment: NSString *myString = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
    NSLog(@"Copied String: %@",myString);

Using this i get the copied string from PDF file

Comment: If some how I call that copy code programmatically the I think the problem can be solved

Comment: It can be done using UIPasteBoard, but the trick is to send the copy selector to the UIApplication not the web view. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623334/how-to-copy-selected-data-from-a-pdf-displayed-in-a-uiwebview