# How to copy selected data from a PDF displayed in a UIWebView

Tags: pdf, uiwebview, uimenucontroller, uiresponder

I am working on a project that displays a PDF in a UIWebView.  I have added another UIMenuItem to the UIMenuController in order to do various things with the text in the UIWebView that has been selected.  The problem is that I am not able to access the selected text in my newly created selector method.  If I use the copy command on selected text first, then I can get that previously copied text from the pasteboard, but a command like [myWebView copy:sender]; called from my new selector does nothing.  How can I receive the selected text in my new selector?  I know this can be done easily with javascript when working with HTML in a UIWebView, how do people usually do this with PDF files displayed in a UIWebView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the copy command from the first responder using this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(copy:) to:nil from:self forEvent:nil];
```

Then you can simply retrieve it from the pasteboard:

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
```

This seems to be the only way to receive the selected text from a UIWebView that is displaying a PDF, the javascript methods will not work with PDF files, only HTML.

Comment: I implement this solution on a proyect and I was wondering if is legal?

Comment: I don't understand why this wouldn't be legal from a programming perspective, but I would be nice if someone more knowledgable might chime in.